# C++ how to print union name integer

Tags: c++

I want to print integer in C++:

```
int n5x = 1;
int n5y = 2;
[...]
int value = 5;

cerr << n+value+x << n+value+y << endl;
```

Is this possible in C++?
Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to do things literally in the same way, but it looks like for what you're trying to do, the tool you're looking for is arrays.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. For instance what are `n`, `x`, and `y`? where do they come from? What do they represent? How do you want to calculate the value you are printing out? Help us help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, you cannot somehow "build" some string at run time and use it as variable name. This is a compile time mechanism, and even if this was a compile time problem, it would be a bad idea.

You most likely want

```
std::vector<int> nx(someLength);
std::vector<int> ny(someLenght);

int value = 5;
cerr << nx[value] << ny[value] << endl;
```

instead. (Or the same thing with `std::array<int, someLength> nx{}` if `someLength` is known at compile time and not big.)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cerr << n+value+x << n+value+y << endl;
> ```

Uhhm what please? You mean to expand symbol names and bind to them at runtime?

No that's not possible.

The closest thing you can get is setting up a `std::map<std::string,int>` and generate the *key* string values as needed.

Comment: I am new in C, can you write example code for me?

Comment: @GiorgiNadiradze C or C++ decide for a language. They're quite different.